# Regular expression to check valid property name in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate user input for a property name to retrieve.

For example user can type *"Parent.Container"* property for windows forms control object or just *"Name"* property. Then I use reflection to get value of the property.

What I need is to check if user typed *legal symbols of c# property* (or just legal word symbols like \w) and also this property can be composite (contain two or more words separated with dot).

I have this as of now, is this a right solution?

```
^([\w]+\.)+[\w]+$|([\w]+)
```

I used `Regex.IsMatch` method and it returned `true` when I passed *"?someproperty"*, though "\w" does not include "?"

Comment: maybe something like ^([\w]+\.)+[\w]+$

Comment: Why don't you use some online tool such as http://www.regexr.com/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the best, but this will work. Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/pR2nL5/1).

```
^@?[a-zA-Z_]\w*(\.@?[a-zA-Z_]\w*)*$
```

Note that
*  Number `0-9` is **not** allowed as first character
* `@` is allowed **only** as first character, but not anywhere else (compiler will strip off though)
* `_` is allowed

**Edit**

Looking at your requirement, the below `Regex` will be more useful, as input property name need not have `@` in it. Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/pN8aM8/1).

```
^[a-zA-Z_]\w*(\.[a-zA-Z_]\w*)*$
```

Comment: Yes, it is very great. In even considers about numbers can't be in the beginning and can be in the middle or end. Thanks a lot

Comment: Though I personally have not encountered properties starting with '@', after the first version of your answer I checked whether properties starting with '@' can be created and it turned out it can, hence I 'll probable use your first answer. Again thank you a lot,also for the link to the site. It is great for learning regex.

Comment: The @ isn't part of the property name--it's C# syntax to tell the compiler that what follows is an identifier. Its intended purpose is for when the identifier matches a keyword. For example, if you want a property called "class" you have to do `public string @class { get; set; }` instead of `public string class { get; set; }` because "class" is a keyword. But the property name is still "class", not "@class". If you use Reflection to look for "@class" it won't find it.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for this too, but I knew none of the existing answers are complete. After a little digging, here's what I found.

### Clarifying what we want

First we need to know *which* valid we want: valid according to the *runtime* or valid according to the *language*? Examples:

- `Foo\u0123Bar` is a valid property name for the C# *language* but not for the *runtime*. The difference is smoothed over by the compiler, which quietly converts the identifier to `FooģBar`.
- For verbatim identifiers (`@` prefix) the language treats the `@` as part of the identifier, but the runtime doesn't see it.

Either could make sense depending on your needs. If you're feeding the validated text into Reflection methods such as `GetProperty(string)`, you'll need the *runtime*-valid version. If you want the syntax that's more familiar to C# developers, though, you'd want the *language*- valid version.

### "Valid" based on the runtime

C# version 5 is (as of 7/2018) the latest version with formal standards: the [ECMA 334](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) spec. Its rule says:

> The rules for identifiers given in this subclause correspond exactly
>   to those recommended by the Unicode Standard Annex 15 except that
>   underscore is allowed as an initial character (as is traditional in
>   the C programming language), Unicode escape sequences are permitted in
>   identifiers, and the “@” character is allowed as a prefix to enable
>   keywords to be used as identifiers.

The "Unicode Standard Annex 15" mentioned is [Unicode TR 15, Annex 7](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html#Programming%20Language%20Identifiers), which formalizes the basic pattern as:

```
<identifier> ::= <identifier_start> ( <identifier_start> | <identifier_extend> )*

<identifier_start> ::= [{Lu}{Ll}{Lt}{Lm}{Lo}{Nl}]

<identifier_extend> ::= [{Mn}{Mc}{Nd}{Pc}{Cf}]
```

The {codes in curly braces} are Unicode classes, which map directly to Regex via `\p{category}`. So (after a little simplification) the basic regex to check for "valid" according to the *runtime* would be:

```
@"^[\p{L}\p{Nl}_][\p{Cf}\p{L}\p{Mc}\p{Mn}\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}]*$"
```

#### All the ugly details

The C# spec also requires that identifiers be in Unicode Normalization Form C. It doesn't require that the compiler actually enforces it, though. At least the Roslyn C# compiler allows non-normal-form identifiers (e.g., `E\u0304\u0306`) and treats them as distinct from equivalent normal-form identifiers (e.g., `\u0100\u0306`). And anyway, to my knowledge there's no sane way to represent such a rule with a regex. If you don't need/want the user to be able to differentiate properties that look exactly the same, my suggestion is to just run `string.Normalize()` on the user's input to be done with it.

The C# spec says that two identifiers are equivalent if they only differ by formatting characters. For example, `Elmo` (four characters) and `El­mo` (`El\u00ADmo`) are the same identifier. (Note: that's the soft-hyphen, which is normally invisible; some fonts may display it, though.) If the presence of invisible characters would cause you trouble, you can drop the `\p{Cf}` from the regex. That doesn't reduce which identifiers you accept—just which formats you accept.

The C# spec reserves identifiers containing "__" for its own use. Depending on your needs you may want to exclude that. That should likely be an operation separate from the regex.

#### Nesting, generics, etc.

Reflection, `Type`, IL, and perhaps other places sometimes show class names or method names with extra symbols. For example, a type name may be given as `` X`1+Y[T] ``. That extra stuff is *not* part of the identifier—it's an unrelated way of representing type information.

### "Valid" based on the language

This is just the previous regex but also allowing for:

- Prefixed `@`
- Unicode escape sequences

The first is a trivial modification: just add `@?`.

Unicode escape sequences are of form `@"\\[Uu][\dA-Fa-f]{4}"`. We may be tempted to wedge that into both `[`...`]` pairs and call it done, but that would incorrectly allow (for example) `\u0000` as an identifier. We need to limit the escape sequences to ones that produce otherwise-acceptable characters. One way to do that is to do a pre-pass to convert the escape sequences: replace all `\\[Uu][\dA-Fa-f]{4}` with the corresponding character.

So putting it all together, a check for whether a string is valid from a C# *language* standpoint would be:

```
bool IsValidIdentifier(string input)
{
    if (input is null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }

    // Technically the input must be in normal form C. Implementations aren't required
    // to verify that though, so you could remove this check if your runtime doesn't
    // mind.
    if (!input.IsNormalized())
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Convert escape sequences to the characters they represent. The only allowed escape
    // sequences are of form \u0000 or \U0000, where 0 is a hex digit.
    MatchEvaluator replacer = (Match match) =>
        {
            string hex = match.Groups[1].Value;
            var codepoint = int.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            return new string((char)codepoint, 1);
        };
    var escapeSequencePattern = @"\\[Uu]([\dA-Fa-f]{4})";
    var withoutEscapes = Regex.Replace(input, escapeSequencePattern, replacer, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
    withoutEscapes.Dump();

    // Now do the real check.
    var isIdentifier = @"^@?[\p{L}\p{Nl}_][\p{Cf}\p{L}\p{Mc}\p{Mn}\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}]*$";
    return Regex.IsMatch(withoutEscapes, isIdentifier, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
}
```

### Back to the original question

The asker is long gone, but I feel obliged to include an answer to the actual question:

```
string[] parts = input.Split();
return parts.Length == 2
  && IsValidIdentifier(parts[0])
  && IsValidIdentifier(parts[1]);
```

### Sources

[ECMA 334](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) § 7.4.3; [ECMA 335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) § I.10; [Unicode TR 15 Annex 7](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html#Programming%20Language%20Identifiers)

Comment: Or there's probably some trivially-easy way to do this with Roslyn. :)

Comment: Could you make the same regex for ECMAScript (JavaScript)?

Comment: Updated link for [ECMA 334](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/)

Answer (score 0):

What you posted in the comments is almost right. But it won't detect single properties like "Name".

```
^(?:[\w]+\.)*\w+$
```

Works as expected. Just changed the + to * and the group to non-capturing group since you are not concerned about groups here.